How to Draw the Function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$ with Level Curves?
I'm currently working on a problem where I need to draw the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$. I've managed to figure out that the level curves of this function are circles with different radii. Specifically, for a given level curve, the radius is $\sqrt{c+1}$, derived from the equation $x^2 + y^2 = c + 1$.
However, I'm struggling with how to actually draw these level curves accurately. Could someone guide me through the steps or provide a method to visualize these circles for different values of $c$? Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

A circle is determined by its radius (which you calculated) and its midpoint. Do you know the midpoints of the circles?

@red_trumpet The midpoints of the circles for the level curves of the function f(x,y) = x² + y² - 1 are at the origin (0, 0). Since the function is symmetric with respect to both the x-axis and y-axis, each level curve is a circle centered at the origin.

Do you know which points of the circle lie on the axes? Then you can use a compass to draw a circle.
